# Listing only the device with the highest RSSI

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

I am developing an android based application that is scanning for existing bluetooth enabled devices. So far I managed to get the name of the devices + the signal strength in dBm. And here comes my question. Is there any way to filter only the device with the strongest signal or in other words just to preview the closest device?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume your RSSI values are of type `int`, if so why not use something similar to the following to determine your highest value:

```
int[] rssiValues = {20, 40, 45, 62, 85, 9, 12 };
int highest = rssiValues[0];
for (int index = 1; index < rssiValues.length; index ++) {
    if (rssiValues[index] > highest) {
        highest = rssiValues [index];
    }
}
```

At the end of this loop `highest` will contain the closest RSSI or Bluetooth device. If you have your devices wrapped in some class you should be able to modify this code to compare your RSSI value.